# Error while installing SQL Server 2012 while having Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, installation

While installing SQL Server 2012, in the installation stage I'm getting the error saying:

> Rule "Prior Visual Studio 2010 instances requiring update." failed.

I'm trying to sought it out by http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=220649 but it is showing error 404.

On the other side I have Visual Studio 2012 in my system. Should I have to download Visual Studio 2010 or is there anything else I can do to start working on SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2012 uses the Visual Studio 2010 shell. Do you have SSMS already installed before installing the server component?

Comment: i have sql server 2012 installed in my system but as i downloaded SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU for the proper installation, while installing this software i am facing the above problem.

Comment: `SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU` doesn't say which versions of SSMS you installed.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Management Studio Express

Comment: I think you should just remove all SQL Server components and instances from your computer and install SQL Server 2017 - then set the Compatibility Level to `110` . Is there a reason you need to use SQL Server 2012 in particular?

Answer (score 0):

The message means that you have already VS 2010 installed, maybe with a former SQL Server installation and this VS 2010 needs to be updated to service pack 1 before you can go on to install SQL Server 2010; you can get SP1 here

https://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-Visual-Studio-2010-Service-Pack-1/3055-2070_4-75451099.html